# Convert column to row after pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

After `pivot_table`, I got the `dataframe` as below:

[image]

I want:

```
product_id   22200103     6902133   6902303   16900119   2600270
user_id    
183503497       1             2        0          0          0
184265397       0             0        2          1          0
208669541       0             0        0          0          1
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: How does the data look before pivot_table?

Comment: Please always post code and data as code and data, never as image, screenshots, links to same etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, these three pandas commands are very similar, figure out which one of them you need:

- [`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html)
- [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) ; more fine-grained control of args
- [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)
- see the pandas doc and also the many existing Q&A on SO to help you decide which.

Next, [`pd.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) by default generates a ***multi-index*** for the rows

- but you can override its `index` and `columns` arguments to get your desired result.
- if you want to transpose them, all dataframes have a [`df.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html?highlight=transpose#pandas.DataFrame.transpose) or `df.T` method. "Convert column to row" is usually (not always) a code smell that you may need that. But there are also `crosstab` and `pivot`, as distinct to `pivot_table`. Please read their manpages and figure out which you really want.

But you can probably avoid the need for transpose by specifying your non-default args to `pivot_table`. For pivoting, please see the doc page linked above, and all the existing SO Q&A showing examples of this.